# Sorting related records in recursive relation

Tags: django, model

I have following class with recursive foreign key. Questions and Answers storing in same table.
Question, type='q'
Answer type = 'a'

I wan tot sort questions by date in DESC, where as dependent answer has to be sorted in ASC order.   How can I do in Django?

```
class Talk(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination)
    text = models.TextField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sup = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child')
    created_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumb_up = models.IntegerField()
    thumb_down = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_dt"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
questions = Talk.objects.filter(type='q')
```

gets you all the question in your default ordering. To get the answers sorted for a specific question, lets say the newest one, use [**`order_by`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
question = questions[0]

sorted_answers = Talk.objects.filter(sup=question).order_by('created_dt')
```

or

```
question.child.order_by('created_dt')
```

Which looks funny because of what you used for your `related_name`

Comment: this seems working, I have {% for talk_child in talk.child.all %} in view. Seems talk.child.order_by('created_dt') is not supported in view. is there any way?